# Set Background Color of TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I am making a heavily skinned application. I am trying to implement a tab control in WPF. I have already began to skin the tabitems and their respective backgrounds. However, I noticed with only two tabitems on the tab control fills the remaining space with just white. What property do I have to style to change this white space? Any help is appreciated, below is a reference picture as well as my xaml.

Picture:

[image: white space wpf tab control]

XAML:

```
<TabControl Margin="0,35,0,0" Background="#1F1F1F">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                                <Grid Name="Panel">
                                    <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" CornerRadius="4,4,0,0" Margin="2,0">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        ContentSource="Header"
                                        Margin="10,2"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#4d4d4d" />
                                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabItem Header="Settings">

            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Results">

            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap your TabControl by a border of the desired color. Put the Margin property in this border:

```
<Border Margin="0,35,0,0" Background="DesiredColor">
  <TabControl Background="#1F1F1F">
    ...
  </TabControl>
</Border>
```

The white (or better transparent) color of the header background is fixed in the control template of TabControl. It would also be possible to change it but it is more complicated. So I would suggest this solution if you just want to have the visual effect.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is not as complicated as it seems, I'll provide the answer in case anyone needs the information in the future;

You will need to right-click the element and edit a copy of the template, then you can edit this line as required,

```
<TabPanel x:Name="headerPanel" Background="COLOR"
```

By default the Background color is set to transparent, hence why placing a border or any other panel behind this object will also work.